# can't use a property name as argument when expecting keyof typeof class

Tags: typescript

I have a class with a static property:

```js
export class names{
    public static readonly rootNames= {
        a: 'a',
        b: 'b',
        c: 'c',
        d: 'd',
        e: 'e',
    };  
}
```

I want to define a function that takes an argument that can only be one of those values:

```js
private getSubFolderByName(name: keyof typeof names.rootNames) {}
// name has type 'a' | 'b'... as expected
```

but when calling the function with e.g. `names.rootNames.a` I get the error that `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"a" | "b" | "c" | "d" | "e"'`, because these properties ('a', 'b', etc.) have type `string`.

I tried:

```js
private getSubFolderByName(name: typeof names.rootNames[keyof typeof names.rootNames]) {}
```

But that is just `string`, again. I need to prevent the types of these properties from widening to string.

Answer (score 0):

First, the function signature needs to be the second version:

```js
private getSubFolderByName(name: typeof names.rootNames[keyof typeof names.rootNames]) {}
```

This creates a union type where the members are the *values* of the `names.rootNames` property. The first version created a union of the names of the *keys* in `names.rootNames`, even if they were coincidentally the same.

Second, to prevent type-widening, declare `rootNames as const`:

```js
export class names{
    public static readonly rootNames= {
        a: 'a',
        b: 'b',
        c: 'c',
        d: 'd',
        e: 'e',
    } as const; 
}
```

This makes the property of e.g. `e` be of type 'e' rather than type `string`.